# Rows from server not showing in Ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datagrid, ag-grid

So I'm using Ag-grid as a table technology to display data I retrieved from a server.

I send a query to the backend like so:

```
var query = QueryService.getQuery();
        if (typeof vm.queryDimensions !== 'undefined' && vm.queryDimensions.keepSorted) {
            query['query'] = vm.queryDimensions.dim;
        }
            query['start'] = vm.pageMarker || 0;
            query['count'] = vm.numPerPage;
            query['sortBy'] ='date';
            query['sortOrder'] = 'desc';
```

Where I indicate the what index to start from, and how much data to retrieve.

The response has 2 parts: The actual data which is an array of objects with the length equal to whatever query['count'] is, and the total number of results found.

I have the columns working fine. It's stored in a variable called colDefs.

After I get the data with my service, this is what I do, based on the Ag-grid docs:

```
DataService.getEventsData(query).then(function(res){
                vm.pageMarker = res.results.length + 1;

                createTableSource(res)

            })


    }

    function createTableSource(data){
        var source = {
            //rowCount: data.resultsFound,
            pageSize: vm.numPerPage,
            getRows: function(params) {
                params.startRow = 0;
                params.endRow = vm.pageMarker;
                var formattedData = formatData(data.results);
                console.log(formattedData);
                params.successCallback(formattedData);
            }
        };
        vm.gridOptions.api.setDatasource(source);
    }

    function formatData(tableData){
        var formattedTableData = [];
        console.log(tableData);
        angular.forEach(tableData, function(v,k){
            var rowObj = {};
            angular.forEach(colDefs, function(i,j){
                if(i.field === 'date'){
                    rowObj['date'] = v.date
                }
            })
            formattedTableData.push(rowObj);



        });
        console.log(formattedTableData);
        return formattedTableData;
    }
```

However, when I check my table, it only shows the columns and the pagination options at the bottom, but none of my actual date. I don't know what else I'm missing with my data.

Comment: Any error on console ? Also did you put a raw height (in pixel) on your ag-grid component or any parent DOM element ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. It was an issue with the height and width I was giving my table. It works now.

Comment: Not sure if this is what happened with you, but my issue was that I was specifying a height on a container div around the ag-grid div, but not the ag-grid div itself. If the ag-grid does not have a height assigned to it, the inside height will be 0 (you may get height from the border(s), but the cells itself will have height 0).

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis I had the same issue. Thanks for the tip